# Problems adding to list and submitting via html form and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, node.js

I am working on a Node.JS app. On the client side I have the following

```
input(type='hidden', name='imgUrl', id="categorylist", value='[]')
...
var images = $.parseJSON($('#categorylist').val())
images.push(data.result.secure_url)
var jsonImages = JSON.stringify(images)
$('#categorylist').val(jsonImages)
```

Then I save to an orchestrate db like this...

```
exports.addToDb = function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.body)
  if(req.params.type) db.put(req.params.type, uuid.v4(), req.body, false)
  next();
}
```

Problem is when it is saved, it looks like...

```
"imgUrl": "[\"https://res.cloudinary.com/dbkbp16kc/image/upload/v1403448829/img.png\"]"
```

A 'normal' one looks like...

```
"imgUrl": [
  "https://f0.bcbits.com/img/a2976218772_2.jpg"
]
```

As you can see it seems the escaping of the quotes is what is causing this issue. Anyone know how I would change the way this is handled?

Comment: why do you have value='[]' , brackets in a string ?

Comment: I dunno because I thought I needed it that way. Is that not the case?

Comment: removing those completely breaks it * making it "input(type='hidden', name='imgUrl', id="categorylist", value=[])"

Comment: Are you using Express? If so, add `app.use(express.bodyParser());` to your app configuration.

Comment: Already there otherwise it wouldn't work at all

Comment: I think it's because $('#categorylist').val(jsonImages), jsonImages is stored as string. Have you tried doing JSON.parse on req.body.imgUrl ?

Comment: Just did that solves it, however, is ugly I would rather just store the object itself. Any way to do it on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you `stringify` the JSON.

Remove  `var jsonImages = JSON.stringify(images)` and instead set `images` direclty as the value of `'#categorylist'`

```
input(type='hidden', name='imgUrl', id="categorylist", value='[]')
...
var images = $.parseJSON($('#categorylist').val())
images.push(data.result.secure_url)
$('#categorylist').val(images)
```

**Update**

@Jackie This `"imgUrl": "[\"https://res.cloudinary.com/dbkbp16kc/image/upload/v1403448829/img.png\"]"` is because you are `stringifying` the JSON. If you need `jsonImages` to be used somewhere else its better you `JSON.parse(images)` while setting it as the val of `#categorylist`

```
var jsonImages = JSON.stringify(images)
...
$('#categorylist').val(JSON.parse(jsonImages))
```

Comment: I will test this when I get home but are you sure it will work? I tried getting rid of the JSON.parse and that seemed to cause everything to fail

Comment: @Jackie This `"imgUrl": "[\"https://res.cloudinary.com/dbkbp16kc/image/upload/v1403448829/img.png\"]"` is because you are `stringifying` the JSON. If you need it to be used somewhere else its better you `JSON.parse(images)` while setting it as the val of `#categorylist`